# MySql Using case concat to convert the format of the total hours from decimal to HH:MM

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to sql and could anyone help me out with this.Thanks in advance

I have a field called display total hours in minutes. If the value of this field is one,Then the convertion query should be executed and the value should be displayed in hh:mm else it should be displayed in decimal format. I can perform this with sql case statements

```
new Zend_Db_Expr("CONCAT(FLOOR(att.Total_Hours),':', LPAD(ROUND((att.Total_Hours - FLOOR(att.Total_Hours)) * 60) % 60,2,0)) as Total_Hours")
```

This query works fine and converts the total hours from decimal to hh:mm format.But this dosent checks any condition, when i include the case statement for this, It throws a syntax error.

```
->joinLeft(array('ET'=>$this->_ehrTables->empType),'emp.Employee_Id=ET.Employee_Type_Id',
                                        array('Display_Total_Hours_In_Minutes' => new Zend_Db_Expr('CASE WHEN ET.Display_Total_Hours_In_Minutes==1 THEN CONCAT(FLOOR(att.Total_Hours),':', LPAD(ROUND((att.Total_Hours - FLOOR(att.Total_Hours)) * 60) % 60,2,0))  ELSE att.Total_Hours END')))
```

Comment: you should add a proper data sample and the expectedc result  ...  which data type is att.Total_hours?

Comment: Total_ hours is of type decimal. I should Convert the total_hours into minutes while viewing the record.In the table it should be saved as decimal.

Comment: If it was me, I'd get rid of all the non-sql stuff and instead focus on the raw sql. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query